# mysqli_result not working converting MySQL to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am converting my old MySQL to mysqli but ran into this problem mysqli result does not work. Looked on the Internet and I founded out that it function had been change, for mysqli result is there an equivalent out there?

Here is my error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bear_mysqli\functions\users.php on line 153

```
function user_exists($con,$username)
{
    $username = sanitize($con,$username);

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`)FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");

    return (mysqli_result ($query, 0)== 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: And the PHP version is >=5 ?

Comment: i using XAMPP V 3.21

Comment: OK so you have no idea what version of PHP you run. Maybe this will give you a clue what you are doing wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: thanks copy the function approximated what mysqli_result did thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no `mysql_result` to `mysqli_result` counter-part. If you're just checking if it exists, use just `->num_rows`:

And use prepared statements instead.

```
function user_exists($con, $username) {

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?';
    $select = $con->prepare($sql);
    $select->bind_param('s', $username);
    $select->execute();
    $select->store_result();

    return ($select->num_rows > 0); // returns bool (true/false)
}
```

Or use an alias for your `COUNT()` and fetch it:

```
function user_exists($con, $username) {

    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS `total` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?';
    $select = $con->prepare($sql);
    $select->bind_param('s', $username);
    $select->execute();
    $select->store_result();
    $select->bind_result($total);
    $select->fetch();

    return $total; // returns the result yielded by alias `total`
}
```

Comment: So, one-line query in php 7 is not works like it was in php 5 in mysql_result without prepared statements?
`return (mysqli_result ($query, 0)== 1) ? true : false;`

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mysqli` in php.ini

Search `extension=php_mysqli.dll` and uncomment in `php.ini` just remove `;` before `extension=php_mysqli.dll`

```
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.

extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and Restart your xampp once you have applied the settings.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to check if the username exists , you can do this :

```
$urexist="SELECT * FROM persons WHERE Email = '$_POST[EMailTxt]'";
$res = mysqli_query($conect,$urexist);//you should add a connection paramenter 
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_NUM);
if($data[0] > 1) {
echo "User Exists";
}
```

Comment: Regarding the question you just deleted, please understand that deleting questions consistently is not going to be helpful in all cases. In fact, deleting many questions can cause the site to rate-limit your further questions.

Comment: @hexafraction i'm  new for the site , it's my mistake that i have not read the terms , i'm banned from asking questions , thank to you

Comment: I don't think you are banned at this point. Please just try to write a good and specific question, and then ask if, if you still need help.

Comment: @hexafraction  the problem that i don't have no information for that app i searched the web and found nothing , maybe my reseach wasn't clear .. i will try again ... thank you :)